# Compare names on exact overlap at indexed positions

Tags: python, character, string-matching

I have a list of names and those that are like "John Smith" vs "J Smith" want to pickup.

difflib and .intersection here don’t help, Levenstein too. If it is:

```
John Smith
J Smith
```

the program should return "ok". If it is:

```
John Smith
Jane Smith
```

it is not "ok".

Comparison should be on space starting from next string, so if it is:

```
M K Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
```

it is "ok". But if it is:

```
M L Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
```

it is not "ok".

Fuzzy regex also not helpful here. How do you solve it in python?

```
import difflib

def get_overlap(s1, s2):
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
    pos_a, pos_b, size = s.find_longest_match(0, len(s1), 0, len(s2)) 
    return s1[pos_a:pos_a+size]

s1 = "John Smith"
s2 = "Jane Smith"

print(get_overlap(s1, s2))
#prints "Smith"
```

```
import jellyfish
jellyfish.damerau_levenshtein_distance('John Smith', 'J Smith')
#prints 3, while I just want to have "match ok"
```

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: it should be just one string with the newline or two separate strings?

Comment: no, it should put names that look like close into a separate file, each name will have ID, so just mark them somehow so can be distinguished because I will be comparing the content of literature (publications) for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the following Pythonic implementation a try. No need for fancy levenshtein distance, luckily. In short, split by different words, and then for each potentially matching section check whether:

- The first characters between the two name sections overlap. If not, then there is **no** match. (e.g. `John` and `Lucas`, `J` and `Lucas` or `J` and `L`)
- The two name sections are both longer than 1 character, and are different. If so, then there is **no** match. (e.g. `Jane` and `John`)

In the cases where these "no match" requirements don't trigger, then there should be an overlap possible. E.g. `J` and `Jane`, or `Lucas` and `Lucas`. I've included extensive comments on how everything works in code, too.

```
def compare(name_one: str, name_two: str) -> bool:
    # Split on spaces
    names_one = name_one.split()
    names_two = name_two.split()
    # If the names have a different number of sub-names
    if len(names_one) != len(names_two):
        return False
    
    # Iterate over the potentially matching parts of the two names
    for name_part_one, name_part_two in zip(names_one, names_two):
        # There is NO match if either the first two characters differ
        if name_part_one[0] != name_part_two[0]:
            return False
        # OR if both names are longer than 1 character *and* different
        if len(name_part_one) > 1 and len(name_part_two) > 1 and name_part_one != name_part_two:
            return False
    # Otherwise, they match
    return True

name_one = "M K Dolsen"
name_two = "Michael Klaus Dolsen"

print(compare(name_one, name_two))
```

Furthermore, here is a quick test suite to show that it works correctly:

```py
pairs = [
    ("M K Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen"),
    ("M L Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen"),
    ("Michael K Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen"),
    ("Michael L Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen"),
    ("Michael Klaus Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen"),
    ("Michael Lucas Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen"),
    ("M K D", "M K D"),
    ("M L D", "M K D"),
    ("John Smith", "J Smith"),
    ("John Smith", "Jane Smith"),
    ("J S", "J S"),
    ("K S", "J S"),
]

for name_one, name_two in pairs:
    print(name_one, "&", name_two, "=", compare(name_one, name_two))
```

Which outputs:

```
M K Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = True
M L Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False
Michael K Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = True
Michael L Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False
Michael Klaus Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = True
Michael Lucas Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False
M K D & M K D = True
M L D & M K D = False
John Smith & J Smith = True
John Smith & Jane Smith = False
J S & J S = True
K S & J S = False
```

Upon inspection, this seems to output exactly what you asked for.

---

To answer to your comment in a question, which was:

> how do you write def not for 2 lists given but for lines in a file, where argument on position 1 line1 should be compared with argument1 on position1 line2?

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    names = f.read().split("\n")

# names is now a list of all names, but we want the every 2 words to be compared together.
for name_one, name_two in zip(names[::2], names[1::2]):
    print(name_one, "&", name_two, "=", compare(name_one, name_two))
```

Now, this is a little bit complex perhaps. I'll explain. `names[::2]` is an abbrevation for `names[0:-1:2]`, where `0` is *start*, `-1` is *stop*, and `2` is *step*. So, this takes a slice of the `names` list, starting from 0, ending at -1, taking every 2nd list element.
`names[1::2]` does the same, but offset by 1.

So, if `names` is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`, then `names[::2]` is `['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']`, and `names[1::2]` is `['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']`. Then, we use the `zip` Python function to "zip" these two lists together.

Printing `zip(names[::2], names[1::2])` gives `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]`, and we can iterate over this with the for-loop like I've shown.

Given a `file.txt` of:

```
M K Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
M L Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
Michael K Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
Michael L Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
Michael Lucas Dolsen
Michael Klaus Dolsen
```

The program outputs:

```
M K Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = True
M L Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False
Michael K Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = True
Michael L Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False
Michael Klaus Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = True
Michael Lucas Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. What am I looking at here? Did you try to change some of the names in the little test suite? And if so, adding `("Michael Kl M K Dolsen", "Michael Klaus Dolsen")` gives me the (correct) output of `Michael Kl M K Dolsen & Michael Klaus Dolsen = False`, rather than `None`.

Comment: nope, that is after the code was run with no "def..." part :) I am also new to python, learn it since 3 weeks

Comment: Solved! Many thanks!

Comment: I see that this was unaccepted, what happened?

Comment: @Tom_Aarsen all good, added another question in the same and then removed it as it is solved. Accepted, thanks!

Comment: how do you write def not for 2 lists given but for lines in a file, where argument on position 1 line1 should be compared with argument1 on position1 line2?

Comment: We don't need to stuff everything in one function. We can separately write a piece of code to convert that file of yours into a list of tuples to be compared. See my edit.

Comment: Got it. And how do you write a function which compares by 2 keys from dictionary and by overlap of 2 other keys? So that first 2 keys are exact match, while second 2 keys are just overlapping